# Eclipse IDE Error: Could not find or load main class javafx.fxml Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse IDE and trying to configure it to fun javafx for the first time. At first I was getting the error message for javafx.controls, after deleting the javafx sdk library from the build path it fixed that error and now i have this one. i have of course installed the e(fx)clipse plugin. Im trying to be thorough in what all I have tried to fix the issue.

I have looked through multiple forums and tried many different approaches. I have added vm arguments to my run configuration:

--module-path "C:\Downloads\openjfx-17.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls, javafx.fxml

i have added my user library to the build path with the appropriate jars. I have deleted the javafx sdk lib from the build path. There are no errors visible in the editor. I have been trying to fix this problem yesterday and today as well for hours! Also here is my module-info code bc i saw in one forum where this was a problem for someone so ill add that info in as well.

```
 module Test {
      requires javafx.controls;
      requires javafx.fxml;
 
      opens application }
```

[Javafx editor/buildpath screenshot--no errors/shows_jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsX3z.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that a VM argument is being treated as your main class name.

You have spaces in a VM argument value.

Separate the added module names by a comma, not a space or comma and space.

Also know that you don’t need add-modules when you have a module-info.java.

*If you continue to have issues getting a basic JavaFX app to run*

If you haven’t been able to get this working after trying for hours, then download Idea and use the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

If you wish to continue with Eclipse, then ignore instructions you find in forum posts.  Instead, exactly follow the official documentation at openjfx.io.